# Error converting varchar to numeric in Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, vb.net, stored-procedures, sqldatatypes

I am trying to insert record into a `SQL Server` table from a XML file. The XML file has some entries for `Depth` column with values that are little different for ex. -8.67991800817151E-0

Can someone please guide me how to convert that value into decimal and insert into table? Thanks.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[IProjectData]   
    @xml XML
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO DHDStrainSet 
        SELECT
            DHDStrainSet.value('(StrainID/text())[1]','VARCHAR(255)') AS StrainID,
            DHDStrainSet.value('(Depth/text())[1]','decimal(18,3)')  AS Depth,
            DHDStrainSet.value('(Strain/text())[1]','decimal(18,10)') AS Strain,
            DHDStrainSet.value('(ProjectID/text())[1]','VARCHAR(50)') AS ProjectID
        FROM
            @xml.nodes('/RSM3DDB/DHDStrainSet') AS TEMPTABLE(DHDStrainSet)
END
```

Sample XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<RSM3DDB>
  <DHDStrainSet>
    <StrainID>SB 1_1ef50386</StrainID>
    <Depth>-5.001987E-9</Depth>
    <Strain>0.99</Strain>
    <ProjectID>Hoop</ProjectID>
  </DHDStrainSet>
</RSM3DDB>
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a sample xml.

Comment: Hi jonathan I have edited question with sample xml file with one entry for your reference.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ could you please explain a bit more how can i do that?

Comment: @Shital that's not valid xml, can you please update.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The XML file has some entries for Depth column with values that are little different for ex. -8.67991800817151E-0. Can someone please guide me how to convert that value into decimal?

Looking at the value `-8.67991800817151E-0` can't be converted to a `decimal`, you would need to look at converting it to a `float`.

So this line:

```
 DHDStrainSet.value('(Depth/text())[1]','decimal(18,3)')  AS Depth,
```

Need's to be changed to (will fix the error):

```
 DHDStrainSet.value('(Depth/text())[1]','float') AS Depth,
```

So in all you said you wanted a `decimal(10,3)`, you could convert that value to a `decimal(10,3)` for example:

```
 convert(decimal(10,3), DHDStrainSet.value('(Depth/text())[1]','float'))  AS Depth,
```

This will output: `-8.68`